# Bourbon two column layout with flexbox

Tags: flexbox, bourbon

I want to create two column layout with flexbox using Bourbon. Here's the code:

```
.module_grid {
  margin: 0 3rem 4rem 0;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  @include display(flex);
  @include flex-direction(column);
  @include align-items(flex-start);
  @include justify-content(flex-start);
  .module_grid_item {
    @include flex(1);
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding: 3rem 0 0 3rem;
    width: 50%; 
    .module_header {
      -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    }
  }
  .module_grid_item.double_module {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

The issue here is that I always get the items displayed in one column. 
Any helpers please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
@include flex-direction(row);
```

instead of `@include flex-direction(row);`. The value of `row` sets the direction left to right, as explained nicely [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).